# Spatial Interactions - ArcGIS Online - Query based on mouse-click

Tags: layers, arcgis-online, proximity, arcgis-portal, arcade

I have a web map, authored and deployed as a web app.
It contains a series of points and lines.

I was wondering if it was possible to create an ability to click anywhere on the map, and have the coordinate of where the click happens be the input to a spatial query of one of the existing layers?

So for example, clicking on the map produces a pop-up telling me the closest point layer, its distance and some attributes from this layer.

I was thinking of using some Arcade expressions, but it seems that you need to have the layer already created to create the popup.

Comment: @JoshC thank you for the response. If you post that as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the built-in web maps / apps, there's not really a way to have popups show up or arcade expressions evaluate without an underlying layer to reference. What you're describing would be possible with a custom JS map/app, but I don't think you'll find anything that meets your needs in the standard tools.